# Java - how should I detect/kill a process if it hangs (previously used watchdog/timeoutobserver)

Tags: java, multithreading, process, timeout, watchdog

I am in the proces of updating some old code and am not sure about the most optimal way to replicate the Watchdog/TimeoutObserver functionality below. However, this is an old way of doing it and I am trying to update it to be more jre7 compliant. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import org.pache.tools.ant.util.Watchdog;
import org.pache.tools.ant.util.TimeoutObserver;


 public class executer implemnts TimeoutObserver {

     public String execute() throws Exception {
         Watchdog watchDog = null;

         try { 
                    //instantiate a new watch dog to kill the process
        //if exceeds beyond the time 
        watchDog = new Watchdog(getTimeout());
        watchDog.addTimeoutObserver(this);
        watchDog.start();

                 ... Code to do the execution .....

              } finally {
             if (aWatchDog != null) {
                  aWatchDog.stop();
             }
         } 
         public void timeoutOccured(Watchdog arg0) {
              killedByTimeout = true;

              if (process != null){
                   process.destroy();
              }
              arg0.stop();
        }

      }
```

Comment: can you put the code for WatchDog ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future.cancel(boolean)` method to let task run asynchronously for some amount of time. To make it work, your `Runnable` should detect it's thread interruption status by using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` (this is code which seems to be inside your `process.destroy()`).

Below is example of *Java Concurrency in Practice* book (chapter 7 "Cancellation"). Consult this book for some other solutions of this task.

```
public static void timedRun(Runnable r, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Future<?> task = taskExec.submit(r);
    try {
        task.get(timeout, unit);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // task will be cancelled below
    } finally {
        // Harmless if task already completed
        task.cancel(true); // interrupt if running
    }
}
```